# How to view source of a locked post?

Tags: discussion, markdown, locked-posts

https://stackoverflow.com/posts/1732454/edit -> `This post is locked and cannot be edited.`

How to view the source?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1732454/revisions, click on source link on the revision you want. Does that work?

Comment: Only now noticed that metas now separate...

Answer (score 5):

As the comment suggested, the source can be viewed by clicking on "revisions", which produce the link like

```
http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1732454/revisions
```

, then clicking on first "source" link:

```
http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1d89c31d-5858-48cb-b5e4-2332753fcd76/view-source
```

Comment: I can not find anything like revisions on a current post in stackoverflow, nor does manually adding this to the URL work. Has this changed since your answer?